# Best way to validate directory and file structure

Tags: java, validation, zip

I have an interface where user can upload zip file containing one or more zips and flat files.

```
Example directory structure -
Main.zip
 - one.zip
   - one
   - one/sample
     - one.xx.xxx.xml
     - one.xx.xxx.xml
   - one/html
   - one.xx.xxxx.xml
   - one.xx.xxxx.xml
 - two.zip
   - two
   - two/sample
     - two.xx.xxx.xml
     - two.xx.xxx.xml
   - two/html
   - two.xx.xxxx.xml
   - two.xx.xxxx.xml
```

I have a convention on how the files and directories should look like. What is the best way to validate them against the convention that I have.

- other simple rules are each zip and their contents follow the same structure except for the start of the file names.

Any ideas on how we can validate the directory structure and files?

Comment: It may be easier to use a server shell called by java to parse directories and files if you use a unix server (in DOS, it would be quite painful...)

Comment: @Tristan - and how I can report the errors back to the interface? Any sample code ?

Comment: Hm, I don't see the problem. Read the ZIP into memory or extract it to temp folder and perform your validation using `java.io`. Can't see a reason for using another language for that...

Comment: @home - I know the straight forward way! I am looking options based on configuration methodology so I don't have to change my code if the rules change

Comment: Your question is too vague. What problem do you have? Reading a zip file in Java? Testing the name of a zip entry? Reporting errors in the UI. Which kind of UI: Swing, plain servlet/JSP, Struts, JSF, Stripes?

Comment: @HonorGod: So you'r looking for something like a rules engine to validate file structures?

Comment: You will have to write all the code. Using some kind of rule engine might avoid writing some of the code in Java, but you'll have to write it some way. I would do it in plain Java, and adapt the code when needed. KISS and YAGNI apply here.

Comment: @JB: OP is using JSP (I removed the JSP tag). But UI shouldn't matter. It's after all just some lines of Java code. OP's problem is not getting the uploaded file or presenting the collected error messages. OP's problem is validating the file structure of an arbitrary zip file. That's beyond UI.

Comment: @BalusC: I asked because he asked in one of his comments: " and how I can report the errors back to the interface?"

Comment: @JB: Hm OK, I interpreted the core problem of that as "How to get the reported errors from the shell?", which is indeed not necessarily trivial. You might have interpreted it differently.